# process.stdin.setRawMode(true) is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to buid a snake game using node with the command line, and I am having an error :

```
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
                  ^
TypeError: process.stdin.setRawMode is not a function
```

I looked it up online, and I found it is depreciated, so it is useful to use :

```
if (process.stdin.isTTY) {
    process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
}
```

I tried to encapsulate both just the line "set raw mode" with the if, as well as the whole function and deleted the stdin line but nothing works, I cannot move the snake using the arrows.
Here is the code without the 'if' (not working in both cases):

```
readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.on('keypress', (str, key) => {
    if (key.ctrl && key.name === 'c') process.exit();
    switch (key.name.toUpperCase()) {
        case 'UP':
            State = Snake.enqueue(State, Snake.NORTH);
            break;
        case 'LEFT':
            State = Snake.enqueue(State, Snake.WEST);
            break;
        case 'DOWN':
            State = Snake.enqueue(State, Snake.SOUTH);
            break;
        case 'RIGHT':
            State = Snake.enqueue(State, Snake.EAST);
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you find an answer ?